# all viewcontrollers turn into blank black screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I am using custom tab bar and 
`UINavigationController` `popToRootViewController`, and then immediately push a new view.
Every thing is working fine in `ios6` but if continues call tab action suddenly my all `viewcontrollers`  turn into black screen in `ios7`.
In my custom tab bar i am writing like this

```
[appDelegate.navBarMain popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[appDelegate.navBarMain pushViewController:appDelegate.vcCalendarViewController animated:YES];
```

is there something wrong  in ios 7[image]

Comment: try setting `[appDelegate.navBarMain pushViewController:appDelegate.vcCalendarViewController animated:` __NO__ `];`

Comment: Did you instantiate pushViewController:appDelegate.vcCalendarViewController?

Comment: @art-divin Thanks dude you save my day!!! now its working fine.so may i know reason why this is not working in ios-7

Comment: @guru no problem! The reason why it __was__ working previously is unknown to me :) I am sure that this is caused by incomplete `UINavigationController` transition. Since `animated:YES` takes about ~0.4 sec time, there is nothing to be shown at the moment when `UINavigationController` tries to show it's root view controller.